# Pandas IntervalIndex get_loc throws KeyError when label equals bound of interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following IntervalIndex for a df called `rates_info`:

```
rates_info.index
Out[173]: 
IntervalIndex([(13.0, 15.0), (15.0, 19.0), (19.0, 24.0)],
              closed='neither',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

The `rates_info` df looks like this:

```
sea_tou       summer_start  summer_end      desc   summer   tou   winter  tou_2
(13.0, 15.0)           6.0         9.0  shoulder  0.11816  13.0  0.08623   15.0
(15.0, 19.0)           6.0         9.0    onpeak  0.17246  15.0  0.10858   19.0
(19.0, 24.0)           6.0         9.0   offpeak  0.06387  19.0  0.06387   24.0
```

When I try to extract either the `summer` or `winter` value for an interval that *equals* either of the bounds, I am getting a `KeyError`:

```
rates_info.iloc[rates_info.index.get_loc(19)]['winter']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-169-cb4c278084f1>", line 1, in <module>
    rates_info.iloc[rates_info.index.get_loc(19)]['winter']

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\interval.py", line 730, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 19
```

or

```
rates_info.iloc[rates_info.index.get_loc(13)]['winter']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-184-5bafb5e11739>", line 1, in <module>
    rates_info.iloc[rates_info.index.get_loc(13)]['winter']

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\interval.py", line 730, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 13
```

When I use a value that is *between* the intervals, it works fine:

```
rates_info.iloc[rates_info.index.get_loc(20)]['winter']
Out[185]: 0.06387
```

or

```
rates_info.iloc[rates_info.index.get_loc(16)]['winter']
Out[186]: 0.10858
```

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: Your intervals are open on both ends. 19 is not in any interval. `rates_info.iloc[rates_info.index.get_loc(18)]` works

Comment: Ah, I see, What does 'open' and 'closed' in this context mean? I assumed open meant including.

Comment: open = excluding, closed = including.